# UILabel font vs NSAttributedString font

Tags: ios

Is there any performance advantage of using UILabel's font and plain text instead of using NSAttributedString with font over whole text.

In other words is there any difference between

```
class Label1: UILabel {
    func display(text: String, with font: UIFont) {
        self.font = font
        self.text = text
    }
}
```

and

```
class Label2: UILabel {
    func display(text: String, with font: UIFont) {
        attributedText = NSAttributedString(
            string: text,
            attributes: [
                NSAttributedString.Key.font: font,
            ]
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Might be helpful** from Programming IOS 9: Dive Deep Into Views, View Controllers, and Frameworks
By Matt Neuburg.
[image]